# Unable to transition to state, getting error that state is not defined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am currently on the main page after invoking 
http://localhost:8199/#/iceberg-ui

I have a state called **iceberg.reconcreate** as defined below.

But when I try to invoke **$state.go('iceberg.reconcreate')** on the click of a button, I get the error that state is not defined.

> angular-ui-router.js:982 Uncaught Error: No such state undefined at
>   Object.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.js:982) at Object.go
>   (angular-ui-router.js:973) at HTMLAnchorElement.
>   (angular-ui-router.js:1383) at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch
>   (jquery.js:4641) at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4309)

**ROUTING**

```
    routingSetup.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
    function routingSetup($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/iceberg-ui");

    $stateProvider
        .state('iceberg', {
            url: "/iceberg-ui",
            templateUrl: "app/iceberg/iceberg.view.html",
            controller: 'IcebergController as icebergCtrl'
        })
        .state('iceberg.reconlist', {
            templateUrl: "app/iceberg/recon/list/recon.list.view.html",
            controller: 'ReconListController as reconListCtrl'
        })
        .state('iceberg.reconcreate', {
            templateUrl: "app/iceberg/recon/create/recon.create.view.html",
            controller: 'ReconCreateController as reconCreateCtrl'
        })
        .state('iceberg.recondetails', {
            templateUrl: "app/iceberg/recon/details/recon.details.view.html",
            controller: 'ReconDetailsController as reconDetailsCtrl'
        })
}
```

**Controller**

```
(function() {
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('iceberg.recon');
myApp.controller('ReconListController', ReconListController);

ReconListController.$inject = ['ReconListService', '$state'];

function ReconListController(ReconListService, $state) {
    var vm = this;

    function getReconciliationList() {
        return {
            load: function(loadOptions) {
                var reconList = ReconListService.getReconciliationList();
                return {
                    data: reconList,
                    totalCount: reconList.length
                };
            },
            update: function(key, values) {
                console.log("calling the UPDATE GRID");
                //Do Nothing, this method is required else the framework throws an error
            }
        };
    }



    vm.createNewRecon = {
        text: "Create New Reconciliation",
        icon: "plus",
        type: "success",
        height: "45px",
        onClick: function(e) {
            $state.go('iceberg.reconcreate');
        }
    };

}
}());
```

**UPDATE** - Updated with controller details

Comment: if you are using `<a>` tag to change state, use `ui-sref="iceberg.reconcreate"` and if not then show the controller code for state change.

Comment: have you inject `$state` in the controller where u use 
` $state.go('iceberg.reconcreate') `

Comment: Is your `iceberg` abstract? try to add `abstract: true,` to `iceberg`

Comment: @tanmay - that is the first state defined in the routing section. Is that the one you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks, that was an oversight from my end. I had a ui-sref defined with the incorrect name and all this while I was thinking it was getting called as a onclick event. My bad, apologies for the same.